# Trying to find values from a stored procedure in c# form that must return value

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, if-statement, return-value

I have a stored procedure in SQL, with coding:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Intrecno FROM MainCallProblems 
ORDER BY Intrecno DESC
```

that I use in my C# code:

```
long oldVal = ExecuteDataReader<MainCallProblems>("spGetMainCallProblemRefNo", null, typeof(MainCallProblems));.First().Intrecno;
```

Please note the field Intrecno in the database is my primary key, a bigint and is an identity(1,1).

This is used in a service, that returns a value. Now currently there is nothing in the table to call, no data.

So how do I find out if there is no data? The return value, which is also the type in the SQL table is a long variable\bigint

I have tried:

```
long newVal = 0;
        long oldVal = 0;
        // Generates list to see if there is anything stored within. If not, makes the first value 1
        List<MainCallProblems> mainCallProblemsList = ExecuteDataReader<MainCallProblems>("spGetMainCallProblemRefNo", null, typeof(MainCallProblems));
        if (mainCallProblemsList != null)
        {
            oldVal = mainCallProblemsList.First().Intrecno;
            newVal = oldVal + 1;
        }           
        else
        {
            newVal = 1;
        }
        return newVal;
```

This is supposed to see if there is anything in the table. If not, the return is a simple 1. If there is, the data is loaded, altered and returned.
But I get an error when running:

> Reason = "System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at GetMainCallProblemRefNo()\r\n  at GetMainCallProblemRefNoResponse

Don't worry about the full error. Just know that there is nothing in the table, which it returns as an error. It doesn't even go through the if statement to assign the data.

How do I rectify this error, without manually adding in a default row in the table. IE:

```
insert into MainCallProblems(Assistant)
values('Joe')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because `mainCallProblemsList` is not `null`... but it *is* empty. And `First()` requires that there's at least one item in the collection.

Use `Any` instead:

```
if (mainCallProblemsList.Any())
{
    oldVal = mainCallProblemsList.First().Intrecno;
    newVal = oldVal + 1;
}           
else
{
    newVal = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add one more condition like below

```
if (mainCallProblemsList != null && mainCallProblemsList.Count > 0)
```